# WPF - Detect Explicit Tab Selection vs. programmatic Tab Selection

Tags: wpf

I have an application where I would like to explicitly set focus to particular content inside of TabItem Content, dependent on whether the user clicked the tab explicitly or whether the tab was activated via code by setting hte SelectedIndex. Specifically I don't want to set focus to the embedded document content when programmatically selected (as I can explicitly force it via code), but I do want to set it when activated via Tab header click.

I haven't been able to effectively intercept the tab header click operation. Tab and tab content container clicks don't seem to fire and inside of the  SelectedIndex_Changed event there's no indication where the activation originated from.

Any ideas what I can look at to determine explicit manual vs. programmatic tab activation?

Answer (score 0):

I had a solution for this. You can capture mouse click event on tab header and set a bool flag. Then check the same flag in 'SelectionChanged' event of tab control, you can do what you want here such setting focus, then reset the flag to identify further clicks. Here is the sample code.

```
<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">
    <TabItem>
        <TabItem.Header>
             <TextBlock Text="ABC" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown"/>
        </TabItem.Header>
        <!--<TabItem.InputBindings>
             <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick"  />
        </TabItem.InputBindings>-->
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="XYZ" />
</TabControl>
```

In code behind you can check like this

```
 private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(isClicked)
            {
                //you can set focus here
                isClicked = false;
            }

        }

        private void TextBlock_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            isClicked = true;
        }
```

You can also try input bindings for tab item to detect the mouse click and raise the command, if you want to set the variable or take any required action. This way will be useful if you are following MVVM

Comment: My headers are more dynamic and I did try using MouseDown on the Header Content's Grid but I had no luck - the mousedown/up events never fired. But maybe I should try the TextBlock instead although that won't handle the entire block.

Comment: In that case, better you try with input binding for the header content, it gives a left click event. Hope this helps.